# How do you form "did" sentences?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

Which one of the following is correct?

"How did you know what marks I got?"

"How did you know what marks I get?"

"How did you know what marks I have got?"

"How did you know what marks I have gotten?"

I remember someone said that you do not need to use past tense once you used "did"?

Comment: You don't need to use the past tense of _know_, but the rule doesn't affect the rest of the sentence. ',,,What marks I get' is wrong, since the speaker has already received the marks.

Comment: @KateBunting Hello Kate! Thanks for commenting, so the other 3 options are correct? How do they differ from each other?

Comment: _Gotten_ is only used in American English. As I'm British, I don't know whether it would be appropriate here or not. _Got_ would be usual; _have got_ would be used of something physical in the speaker's possession ('how many pens I have got').

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks Kate :)